# SQL - select within select in query

Tags: sql, select, average

In a very standard question of selecting all item names and their prices for those prices greater than the average price.
The query using having has the form:

```
'''SELECT Name, Price FROM items
GROUP BY Name
HAVING Price > 
(SELECT AVG(Price) FROM items )
;'''
```

It seems that only when AVG is used in a SELECT statement then it is returning the column average. Else if I use `HAVING Price > AVG(Price)` nothing is returned. Why is an additional SELECT statement required, instead of just using AVG on Price?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just how `GROUP BY` works. In the `SELECT` part of the query, you can only have the columns that are used in the `GROUP BY` clause, or the aggregates, like `MIN`, `MAX`, `AVG`, `SUM`, etc. In this case, what's your aggregate of the column Price that you want to output? you should specify that.

Alternatively, you could use a windowed function for calculating the average price for each name unit, and then add the subquery to filter on that:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT Name, Price, AVG(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY Name) AS Average_Price
      FROM items) AS X
WHERE X.Price > X.Average_Price
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your best option is a simple subquery in `WHERE` condition

```
select i.*
from items i
where Price > (
    select avg(Price) avgPrice 
    from items ii
    --where ii.Name = i.Name /* add this line if you need average to be calculated per Name */
)
```